# Delect white space of list in python

Tags: python, list, whitespace

How can I delect the white space in a list?

I have:

```
text = ["      Hello", "     how are      ","you   "]
```

I want:

```
text = ["Hello","how are","you"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the question you want to ask.  You want to ask "how can I delete leading and trailing spaces?"  You use `.strip` for that.

```
text = [s.strip() for s in text]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List = ["      Hello", "     how are      ","you   "]
List = [value.strip() for value in List]
print(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip method on str and list comprehension, e.g.

```
text = ["      Hello", "     how are      ","you   "]
withoutWhiteSpace = [t.strip(' ') for t in text]

print(withoutWhiteSpace)
['Hello', 'how are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the white spaces at the beginning & at the end of each item in list by using below List comprehension procedure.

We are looping through each item in the list "text" & then using [python string.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) functionality to remove the whitespace.

`text = [item.strip() for item in text]`